# What is the format for creating an href link using a variable?

Tags: jquery, html, href

I want my href link to be based on domain names that may change but always utilize the same page name, about.html.

The javascript code below identifies whether the domain should be abc.com or xyz.com.  My problem is that I do not know how to write the HTML code so that the href will equal:
the referring link of abc or xyz plus about.html.

Javascript

```
$(".abcORxyz").html(document.referrer);
```

HTML

```
<a href="What do I need to put here? + .about.html">Other About Page</a>
```

Comment: What are you using on the server side? Anything that generates dynamic pages, such as PHP? This would be the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put anything in the `href` attribute at all. You seem to be using jQuery, so you can use jQuery to set the `href` attribute upon page load.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aboutLink").attr("href",document.referrer + ".about.html");
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="aboutLink" href="#">Other About Page</a>
```

As a side note, I encourage you not to use `document.referrer` for this purpose, because you never know what that referrer actually is going to be. What if Google is what landed the visitor on the page you're using this on? The link would end up looking something like `https://www.google.com/search?q=about&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a.about.html`.

Comment: Ok, that is helpful to know the jquery approach; but just so I know the capabilities of dynamic links in HTML, is there a way to build an href link in html with a variable?

Comment: @JohnMontague, no this is not possible with pure HTML. You must either use JavaScript (or jQuery as it a framework for JavaScript) to change the property after the page loads. To elaborate further, pure HTML is *not* dynamic.

Comment: @JohnMontague, you could use a server side language (e.g. PHP, ASP.Net, Perl, etc.) to inject a variable though. If you can tell which language you're using (if any) then I will update my answer to show how to do with that language.